# git auto fetch before a diff

Tags: git, githooks, tortoisegit

Is there a way to make git fetch from a remote right before you do a diff? I can't for example see a hook that would allow this .. If you cannot do this via a hook is there a genuinely good reason or is it just functionality that doesn't currently exist / there is no demand for?

Is it possible via any client tool (e.g. I use TortoiseGit for Windows)

Personally I think it would be useful as I always want to compare to the latest version of the remote and I'm worried i'll forget to fetch ..

Thanks

Comment: You can create a alias which does fetch and diff.

Comment: yep this would work from the command line, a hook could be used by a client tool

Comment: @AD7six that is not the case, as I am not questioning existing functionality, i am questioning functionality that (i believe) does not exist .. no tool is completely perfect as it is that's why stuff is constantly being developed, even in git - the latest source release was only last week

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a genuinely good reason or is it just functionality that doesn't currently exist / there is no demand for?

`git fetch` implies a remote access; `git diff` does not.

Almost all git commands are supposed to be done locally (which explains why they are so fast). Adding a fetch by default for any diff operation would make said diff very slow.

So creating a git alias for that is a viable alternative.

---

> the alias works except ideally I'd want client tools (e.g. tortoisegit) to be able to use this functionality which they could with hooks

You can consider [setting up an external diff program](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-progs) (a wrapper which does the fetch before calling the diff)

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/SettingsProgs.png]

Comment: i guess my question wasn't clear, i didn't mean why does it not automatically fetch before every diff, i meant why is there no pre-diff hook if you wanted to implement this .. the alias works except ideally i'd want client tools (e.g. tortoisegit) to be able to use this functionality which they could with hooks

Comment: @user555265 OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks v much - that is certainly useful to know and I will use this to achieve what I'm looking for. Personally I think it would be great if you could do it via a hook, that way you would not need to customize each tool you use..